# Textfiled to limit to only numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a Textfield and i want to limit this field to input only numbers and no Alphabets/Alphanumeric.Right now the field accepts max 10 digits but accepts all inputs.
Please help.

```
document.getElementById('Caseid').onchange = function()
{
      if(this.value.length !=10){
       alert("Please check the Caseid again");
      }
      if(this.value < 4){
           this.value = "";
      }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `<input type="number">`?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing a few days ago and decided to just change the keyboard output to decimal only.
It fixed my problem (but it is still possible to enter alphabetic key from the keyboard on the simulator)

Anyway, hope this help if not, I am also interested in a code version for this fix!